# Camera2 is scaled on Front Camera of Nexus 7 2013

Tags: android, camera

I'm trying this sample: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic

When I change to Front Camera, the Camera is scaled. When I stop and resume the application, it can work perfect.

I'm using Nexus 7 2013 OS 5.0.2

I change to Front Camera by comment this code:

```
// We don't use a front facing camera in this sample.
if (characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)
        == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {

//                    continue;
//                }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem when trying to capture via front camera

My solution was to comment out some lines in AutoFitTextureView.java

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        //if (0 == mRatioWidth || 0 == mRatioHeight) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
       /* } else {
            if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight) {
                setMeasuredDimension(width, width * mRatioHeight / mRatioWidth);
            } else {
                setMeasuredDimension(height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight, height);
            }
        }*/
    }
```

So no matter what or when it'll set it's width&height again.